# How to format CSS of a dropdown menu so if the 'parent' dropdown is current then the children will not take the formatting of the parent

Tags: html, css

How can I stop the children of a dropdown inheriting the parent/titles formatting when the 'active/current' page. For example below. The menu item will highlight green when it is the current active page. 'The about us' is an individual page as well as being the parent dropdown for 'what we do etc'.

Looking through my css, if I keep the .active pseudoclass as it is currently, when 'about us' is given the class 'active' the 'about us' is highlighted but so are the dropdown items of it. This then changes positioning and stuffs up the menu.

To fix this do I need to make more classes/ids and be more specific in the formatting or is there a quicker and more logical way of just highlighting the parent only.

Working Example:

a) Home as 'active':
http://jsfiddle.net/homer5677/r4XeS/

b) About us as 'active':
http://jsfiddle.net/homer5677/KKuf3/

Code:

**Home HTML**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='index 2.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='aboutus.html'><span>About Us</span></a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href='ourhistory.html'><span>Our History</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='whychooseus.html'><span>Why Choose Us</span></a></li>
          <li class='last'><a href='testimonials.html'><span>Testimonials</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>`
  </ul>
</div>`
```

**About Us HTML**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li ><a href='index 2.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li class='has-sub, active'><a href='aboutus.html'><span>About Us</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='ourhistory.html'><span>Our History</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='whychooseus.html'><span>Why Choose Us</span></a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='testimonials.html'><span>Testimonials</span></a></li>
     </ul>
   </li> 
 </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #cssmenu {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
   margin-left: 0%; /*to get over 10%*-fixed now*/


 }

#cssmenu > ul {
  width: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 10%;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: #222222;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #6ec919;
 /*fix border whole way*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;

 }

#cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab {
  display: none;
  /* Hide for large screens */

}

#cssmenu > ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
 margin-right: 0px;/**/
 margin-left: -5px;/* get rid of tiny space between items*/
 padding-left: 0px;/**/
}

#cssmenu > ul li.right {
 float: right;
}

#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub {
 position: relative;

}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub:hover ul {
 display: block;
 }

#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
 display: none;
 width: 250px;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
 background: #222222;
 /*border: 1px solid #6ec919;
  /* fix for best---border-left: 2px solid #6ec919; */
  border-bottom: 5px solid #6ec919; /* or 5 to match above*/
  border-top: 0 none;
  font-size: 14px;
 }
 #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li {
  display: block;
  }


 #cssmenu > ul li.quote a {

  color: #6ec919;
 }

 #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a {
  background-image: url('images/caret.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% -95%;
  }

 #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a.active,
 #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a:hover {
  background: #6ec919 url('images/caret.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% 195%;
  }

 #cssmenu > ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px 11px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;

 }



 /*active on hover below */
#cssmenu > ul li.active{
 background: #6ec919;
 color: #fff;
}

 #cssmenu > ul li.active a:hover{

  color: #000;
 }
 /*above*/


 #cssmenu > ul li a:hover {
  background: #6ec919;
  color: #fff;
 }
```

Comment: I've seen a lot of similar questions lately, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254384/add-another-css-style-to-child-elements-which-are-also-parents And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226817/set-dropdown-menu-parent-background-to-transparent-keep-children-opaque And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849536/css-change-parents-background-on-hoverhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849536/css-change-parents-background-on-hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then do this,

then put same changes on `#cssmenu > ul > li:hover`

and remove `#cssmenu > ul li a:hover` part. Which will give effect like below link,

http://jsfiddle.net/r4XeS/3/

Comment: @Brijech Gajjar |
No, I mean if you change the class 'active' to being on the aboutus. See example below, but I would just like the green behind 'About Us' and not the children. http://jsfiddle.net/homer5677/r4XeS/2